# mysql datediff many columns

Tags: mysql

I am use php and mysql.
My table:

```
Columns1 |Columns2| Columns3| Columns4| Columns5| Columns6
date1    |date2   | date3   | date4   | date5   | date6
```

I need Datediff between Date2-Date1 as D1 , Date4-Date3 as D2 , Date6-Date5 as D3
and need result table display is below:

```
D1           |  D2          | D3
Datediff days| Datediff days| Datediff days
```

How to get this result?
thank you.

update
my code:

```
select id,datediff(`Columns2`,`Columns1`) as D1 from `Apr` union all select id,datediff(`Columns4`,`Columns3`) as D2 from `Apr`
```

it will show

```
id | D1
```

I need the result is:

```
 id | D1 | D2
```

Comment: You've practically described it yourself, you need `DATEDIFF` selected three times, with the specified columns. Have you tried to write the query yourself?

Comment: Yes I try it ..but it is not work....

Comment: Can you please include your best effort in the question so that we can help you determine what's wrong?

Comment: select id,datediff(`Columns2`,`Columns1`) as D1 from `Apr` union all select id,datediff(`Columns4`,`Columns3`) as D2 from `Apr`.....it will show id | D1 ... not the id | D1 | D2

Comment: For future reference: include additional information by adding it to your question (click the edit link at the bottom). Comments aren't very suitable for code. And please include the entire query, don't leave anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use a `UNION` here because you're selecting from the same table and you don't have any complex conditions on which you select your data. You can get it all in a single select statement:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  DATEDIFF(Columns2, Columns1) AS D1,
  DATEDIFF(Columns4, Columns3) AS D2,
  DATEDIFF(Columns6, Columns5) AS D3
FROM Apr;
```

It was `UNION` that wasn't giving you the right results. You wanted three separate columns and you were trying to unify three selections with one column, so it unified them all into one.

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( (DATEDIFF(Columns2, Columns1)+1) SEPARATOR ',') as D1
FROM Apr
it will disply D1:2,3,4

Comment: If I use Select id,name,GROUP_CONCAT( (DATEDIFF(Columns2, Columns1)+1) SEPARATOR ',') as D1 FROM Apr  mysql will show error....is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

Comment: @jason That's a whole different problem and is not possible to tell what's wrong since you're not showing the entire query. It's not suitable for comments, I'd suggest opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like :-

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date2, date1)
```

For ex-;

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("2017-06-25 09:34:21", "2017-06-15 15:25:35")
```